# How do i use HTML image tag for responsive images?

Tags: html, css, dom, browser, srcset

I am trying to use responsive images for my web page but it seems like chrome is always fetching the full-width image (1280x1920) when trying in smaller viewports. I tried clearing the cache and using incognito mode, but nothing works.

> Chrome: Version 80.0.3968.0 (Official Build) dev (64-bit)

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

```
<img 
src="https://develop:8065/app/uploads/2019/11/photo-1574950578143-858c6fc58922-768x1152.jpeg" 
srcset="
https://develop:8065/app/uploads/2019/11/photo-1574950578143-858c6fc58922-375x563.jpeg 375w, 
https://develop:8065/app/uploads/2019/11/photo-1574950578143-858c6fc58922-768x1152.jpeg 768w,
https://develop:8065/app/uploads/2019/11/photo-1574950578143-858c6fc58922-1280x1920.jpeg 1280w" 
sizes="(max-width: 375px) 375px, (max-width: 768px) 768px, (max-width: 1280px) 1280px, 1920px" 
alt="" 
title="1">
```

Comment: Try removing the `src` attribute...

Comment: Have you tried adding a `style` attribute? Eg. `style="width:375px;"`

Answer (score 0):

One option can be to add `width="100%"` attribute to make the images responsive.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Responsive Image</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img 
      src="https://api.nasa.gov/assets/img/general/apod.jpg" 
      width="100%"
      alt="NASA Astronomy Image" />
  </body>
</html>
```